# Server error in MVC5 application after recreate the data model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I just deleted and recreated my entity framwork data model(.edmx file) because the "update model from database" option was not working well, leaving some table columns in the model when I deleted them from database.
The thing is that now my project is broken and i'm having this error when i run my application. Any ideas how can i fix it?

Server Error in '/MonitoreoIntegrado' Application.

No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'EntityFramework (1)' ni una de sus dependencias. La definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide con la referencia al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'EntityFramework (1)' ni una de sus dependencias. La definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide con la referencia al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'EntityFramework (1)' could not be loaded.

AVS: El registro del enlace de ensamblado está desactivado.
Para habilitar el registro de errores del enlace de ensamblado, establezca el valor de Registro [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) como 1.
Nota: existe una disminución del rendimiento asociada registro de errores del enlace de ensamblado.
Para desactivar esta característica, elimine el valor de Registro [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace:

[FileLoadException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'EntityFramework (1)' ni una de sus dependencias. La definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide con la referencia al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +234
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +108
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +25
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +34
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +49

[ConfigurationErrorsException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'EntityFramework (1)' ni una de sus dependencias. La definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide con la referencia al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +772
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +259
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +163
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +230
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +76
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +343
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +176
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +734

[HttpException (0x80004005): No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'EntityFramework (1)' ni una de sus dependencias. La definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide con la referencia al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +579
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +112
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +716

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1073.0

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was very weird. There was a folder in my project named `_bin_deployableAssemblies`. I deleted this folder from my local disk and then excluded this folder from my project and now all is working perfect again.